# Can mouse variables of p5.js be used on a touchscreen device? (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, touch, mouse, p5.js, touchscreen

Is it possible to use mouseX and mouseY on touchscreen devices? If tapped-and-dragged on a touchscreen, will it keep updating mouseX and mouseY? It is important in my code for the mouse variables to continuously be used so it's important for them to keep updating on a touch screen even when dragged not only for tapping and releasing. If this doesn't work, then what are some alternatives from p5.js itself which work perfectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also touch events build into p5, check this example:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/touchStarted

and this:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/touches

Comment: added the other example too.